# How to configure Logback's ContextInitializer?

Tags: logback, logback-classic

In versions `1.3.8` and earlier of Logback, it was possible to configure the `ContextInitializer` using a resource file using its `configureByResource` method, e.g.

```
new ContextInitializer(loggerContext).configureByResource(
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("pattern-console-logback.xml"));
```

In version `>=1.3.9`, this method completely disappeared. How then can I achieve the same configuration ?

The `autoConfig` method doesn't provide what I need. The flavour using a `classLoader` is a bit obscure to me as I wasn't able to find any example or way to use it properly.